# How to Pass Bitmap[] between 2 fragments

Tags: java, android, arrays, bitmap, android-asynctask

Im using `AsyncTask` to download some images from `url`. The downloaded images i save in `Bitmap array`. Once they are saved i dont know how to pass them from one `fragment` to another. Can someone help please?

Pressing download Button:

```
d.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String [] urlArray = new String[]{URL_IMAGE_1, URL_IMAGE_2,URL_IMAGE_3,URL_IMAGE_4, URL_IMAGE_5};
            asyncTaskA.execute(urlArray);
            FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.fragmentMain);
            frameLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            FragmentImages fragmentImages = new FragmentImages ();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragmentMain,fragmentImages );
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
```

In MainFragment method:

```
 public void getImages(Bitmap [] bitmaps){
    imagesDownloaded = bitmaps;//private Bitmap [] imagesDownloaded;
    images = imageDownloaded; //public stati Bitmap [] images;

}
```

In AsyncTask

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap[] bitmaps) {

    fragmentMain.getImages(bitmaps);

}
```

In FragmentImages so far

```
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Bitmap[] bitmaps = FragmentA.images; // The array is null, why??

}
```

What im missing?
Im new with programming.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: for downloading images from server please try to Use picasso

Comment: Why are you passing bitmap,you can pass file or Uri and now for android 7 you can use FileProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its null because you dont know how to AsyncTask works

```
asyncTaskA.execute(urlArray);
```

So AsyncTask started

```
       FragmentImages fragmentImages = new FragmentImages ();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentMain,fragmentImages );
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
```

You opened fragment and ask for images - there are no images, so you have `null`

After some time images downloaded here. So you have:

1. No images diplayed
2. Memory leak

Good way is passing url of image to other fragment and download it with `Picasso` or same library.

If you SO need to use `AsyncTask` you had to open fragment in `onPostExecute` method. Also if you need to pass `Bitmap` variable you can set it to `Application` class or custom singleton or to your `Activity` class for example.